# How can I log org-mode clock entries to current clock and to an index file?

Tags: org-mode

I use org-mode to [clock working time](http://orgmode.org/manual/Clocking-work-time.html).  I also have a few [capture templates](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-templates.html) which work great for, well, capturing thoughts, notes, tasks, etc, without a lot of disruption.

What I would like to add but I'm not sure how to go about it, is to have a capture template for logging notes on the currently open clock.  I would like the captured text to go to both the current clock as well as to an index file which will be just a running index of what I logged.  The result of this will be that my clock entries would look like this:

```
** TODO Setup custom capture template for logging to clock and index file
   CLOCK: [2014-09-03 Wed 08:43]
   - this is a captured note, posted an update to SOF (this one)
   - this is a captured note, posted question to SOF
   CLOCK: [2014-09-03 Wed 08:07]--[2014-09-03 Wed 08:29] =>  0:22
   - this is a captured note, scratched my head a while
   CLOCK: [2014-09-02 Tue 17:07]--[2014-09-02 Tue 17:25] =>  0:18
   - another captured note
```

For this same time period, my task-index.org file would look like:

```
[2014-09-03 Wed 09:34] - this is a captured note, posted an update to SOF (this one)
[2014-09-03 Wed 09:05] - this is a captured note, posted question to SOF
[2014-09-03 Wed 08:07] - this is a captured note, scratched my head a while
[2014-09-02 Tue 17:15] - another captured note
```

The timestamp in the index file would be the link-back target (%a in the template?) from where the entry was originally captured could not illustrate that link using the SOF syntax).

I don't have anything to share because my biggest problem is that I'm not sure where to begin. I could create the capture template but I'm not sure how I would make it *put a plain list item in the current clock* nor how to *make a hook from a template that would go off and put in the index entry*.

Help of any sort would greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just stumbled across [PersonalJournal](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OrgJournal) which is not exactly what I was after but pretty close in that I can manually create the links while I'm making the journal entries.